# Using Asana Boards in Kanban mode

Tags: asana

Our (software development) team is using Asana and has broken down requirements, which were entered into the list view of Asana.
We have sections representing epics, and tasks below them representing stories.

I would now expect to use the 'List' view in Asana as the backlog, and track individual stories on the Board view as soon as we start working on them (moving them across the board in Kanban style, with status such as To Do, In Progress, Done). However, it seems the board view is not offering a way to do this.

It seems the only thing the Asana board can do is represent their "sections" (which are something like topics) as columns. If that's really the only thing it can do, I don't understand what the whole board should be good for.

There is another question on this topic, but with no result:
[Managing team workflow using Asana and Kanban principles](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6052/managing-team-workflow-using-asana-and-kanban-principles)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Asana before but it seems that it does allow for dragging and dropping tasks from one column to the next.

https://asana.com/guide/help/views/boards#gl-drag-and-drop

[image]

[image]

Let me know if I may have misunderstood your question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - obviously they do offer these boards, but my issue is with configuring the columns.